# How to hide texts of loading JS files from the bottom of the scree in Ionic 4 application?

Tags: javascript, android, angular, ionic4, mathjax

I am using MathJax library in my Ionic application. In the index.html file I put -

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
 MathJax.Hub.Config({
  showProcessingMessages: false,
  tex2jax: { inlineMath: [['$','$'],['\\(','\\)']] }
 });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_HTMLorMML">
```

In the Online-test page I have -

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
 eval('MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub])');
}
```

When I go to Online-test page I can see JS files are getting loaded at the bottom. I want these files to be loaded at the background without showing these texts. I have attached an screenshot for better understanding. Thank You!
[Online-test screen with JS files loading texts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjxGU.png)

Comment: consider downloading the library and storing a local copy in your `src/assets` directory

Comment: @JohnTyner Thanks for your response. I tried with putting local copy in assets but same thing happening.
`<script type="text/javascript" async src="assets/MathJax.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Set the `messageStyle` option to `'none'`:

```html
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
 MathJax.Hub.Config({
  messageStyle: 'none',
  tex2jax: { inlineMath: [['$','$'],['\\(','\\)']] }
 });
</script>
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/options/hub.html?highlight=messageStyle) for more details.